# Why do tcp implementation use byte sequence number and not segment number for flow control?

Tags: tcp

For the flow control TCP uses `Sequence number` and `acknowledgement number` which are the starting byte number in the segment.

While the segment is sent or received it goes as a whole. So from the socket perspective, either a segment as a whole is received or the complete packet containing the segment was lost.

example:
If the segments are created as follows:

Segment 1: seq 1 to seq 1000

Segment 2: seq 1001 to seq 2000

Segment 3: seq 2001 to seq 3000

If the packet containing segment 2 (seq 1001 to 2000) is dropped, the receiving end does not receive seq 1000 to 2000. There isn't a way that it will receive part of the segment. So the receiver sends ack for 1001.

While implementing TCP why did the creators not use segment numbers? Like in the above example sender could send `sequence number` as *`segment`*  1,2 and 3  and the receiver could use `acknowledgement number` as *`segment`* 1,2 and 3. If there is a drop receiver could send   ack for the next expected segment (Segment 2 in our example)

This is could have saved space in each TCP header.

Comment: The sequence number directly relates to the receive window without further calculations. Segments can vary in size and can be sent without all data - using the sequence number makes such not consequential in calculations. Retransmissions are unlikely and the segment already contains the sequence number - it does not contain a “segment number”. The “segment number” (if added) would also be 4 bytes, saving no space over a 4 byte sequence number, as 2-bytes would be far too small (65k values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the window size can vary based on the congestion of the network. Therefore, the segment size can also vary. So using the sequence number for byte is more appropriate than for segment.

If one of your segments is lost, you have to retransmit it but maybe with another segment size (maybe a smaller size if the network is congested). So, if you use sequence number for segment then it exists a case as below:

1. You transmit 3 segments `segment 1, 2, and 3`, each with size `100 bytes`
2. Segment 2 is somehow lost and you need to retransmit `segment 2 and segment 3` but with different sizes. Now let's assume you will retransmit `segment 2' with size 50 bytes, segment 3' with size 50 bytes, segment 4' with size 50 bytes, and segment 5' with size 50 bytes` due to the congestion of the network.
3. Now the `segment 2'` arrives first, then the old `segment 3` arrives (maybe due to some congestion or long buffer or propagation delay or something).
4. At the receiving host, it will receive `segment 1, segment 2' and segment 3` and later when it receives `segment 3'`, it will discard it.
5. The receiving host will also receive `segment 4' and segment 5`.

Now, you have no clue to determine what has gone wrong and you have to retransmit the whole message again.